# C#: GetReportParameters throwing HTTP 401 error

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, reporting-services

In my ASP.Net WebForm Application I have a Class that shows the Report popup when user clicks on a button. One part of the code is this one:

```
        ReportingService2005 rs = new ReportingService2005();
        ReportExecutionService re = new ReportExecutionService();
        rs.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(confEntity.DBUser, DBPassword, confEntity.DBServer);
        re.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(confEntity.UsuarioBanco, SenhaBanco, confEntity.ServidorBanco);   

        string _historyID = null;
        string _deviceInfo = null;
        string _format = "PDF";
        string _encoding = String.Empty;
        string _mimeType = String.Empty;
        string _extension = String.Empty;
        bool _forRendering = true;
        string[] _streamIDs = null;
        string _reportName = reportName;
        ReportService.ParameterValue[] _parameters = null;
        ReportService.DataSourceCredentials[] _credentials = null;
        ReportExecution.Warning[] warnings;

        ReportService.ReportParameter[] parameters = null;

        // Getting the parametters.
        parameters = rs.GetReportParameters(_reportName, _historyID, _forRendering, _parameters, _credentials);
```

Now I'm trying to attach this report as a PDF file to an email. For this I am using my serice project that automatically sends email. But this part:

```
parameters = rs.GetReportParameters(_reportName, _historyID, _forRendering, _parameters, _credentials);
```

is throwing `HTTP 401: Unauthorized` error.

I am using here the same report name that I am using on my Web Project `/D_ReportServer/00-PaymentReport`

Since they are diferente projects located on different fodlers, should I change the report name or something like this?

Comment: Typically 401 error are related to access control. Why are you setting credentials to null? 
    ReportService.DataSourceCredentials[] _credentials = null;

Comment: I just edited the code. I put the way that credentials are being passed to ReportService and ReportExecution. And that is the way it is working on the WebProject... just setting these credentials and let the `[] _credentials` as null. I don't know how it is working but it is